# Presenting on a conference as a Master Student... common or unusual?

Tags: masters, conference, presentation

I am a master's student of Linguistics and am just finishing my first year of the master's programme. For one of my term papers I am currently doing an empirical study, on a topic I think is really important and with striking results. While browsing on the Internet I found a CfP for a conference on a field of research into which my study would fit perfectly.

Now my question is: Is it weird to submit an abstract in hopes of presenting on that conference, even though I am only a master's student? 
Do I have any chance at all to present there or do most conference-organizers immediately dismiss master students because they are not experienced enough? (It is not a student's conference or anything similar)

I just don't know anyone who is experienced enough with these sorts of things to ask them...

Answer (score 2):

I don't have experience as for the linguistics conferences, but from my observations I can tell that while master students' papers are not common, they are not unheard of (especially, but not limited to, as coauthorship with master thesis supervisor). 
There are three remarks that I can make in your situation:

- If the conference has double-blind review policy you should be judged based on the merits of your work and your academic status would be irrelevant.
- Did you try talking with your supervisor about the paper: maybe she can suggest a coauthorship to increase the acceptance chances?
- Generally my advice would be to submit the abstract: what do you have to lose?

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The thing is, my topic doesn't really fit into the research fields of my supervisors (we are really free in our topic choices), so co-authorship is not really possible. Also, it is not a master's thesis or anything, but "just" a term paper, and it's not published or anything. I guess I'm just worried about making a fool of myself... but I guess you are right... what do I have to lose?

Comment: I'm also not familiar with your field, but you won't make a fool out of yourself. Make sure to get your supervisor, professor, other students, etc to read over your paper to look for any mistakes, and then submit it and see what happens.